# Deploying to Azure App Service timing out without message

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment, azure-appservice

Previously, I've been able to deploy my Next.js app to App Service with no problems on a Linux server with the B1 plan (a dev plan). Recently, however, I created a new app on Azure App Service that runs on the P1 production plan, and once again deploying to that was smooth and I had no problems.

Then, I went back to deploy my app on the B1 plan and deployment has been timing out without giving me any error messages. I've tried numerous times to deploy but it spends hours stuck in this state, without giving me any timeout errors, one time I even left it for six hours:

[image: Azure App Service Output in VSCode]

I should also point out that I'm using the Azure App Service extension on VSCode to deploy. Additionally, deploying to the P1 plan is still going smooth even though the B1 plan deployment isn't.

Comment: What was your build time like on the B1 services before, and did your app change in any way that would affect the build time between when it built on the B1 machine and when the build failed? I have had problems with timeouts during package fetching / installs on the Basic tiers when they surpass a certain length (600s?).

What's the duration like on the P1s?

Comment: @UpQuark on the B1 previously it was usually somewhere between 20mins-40mins and with P1 it's usually around 20mins. I don't believe any changes made to my app would have changed the build time because deploying on P1 is still very smooth unless those changes somehow disadvantage B1 specifically.

Comment: Hm... yeah I can only speculate but I've had similar problems where on slow servers, the package installation that ran on the destination service after doing an Azure deploy was slow enough that it would just silently fail after some large period of time.


Are you running your app directly on an app service's "file system" or are you using a container for it? For apps with complicated installs I've found it labor-saving to frontload them into Docker containers (which in my cases I've needed to use anyway), but that obviously adds the big overhead of Docker if you arent using it.

Comment: @UpQuark I'm just running it directly in app service's file system, but doesn't app service automatically create a docker container and run it if I don't deploy one? I've seen it in the server logs before.

Comment: I want to add an update that deploying to the P1 plan has also gotten this issue.